# Prestashop 1.7 - show custom success message on file upload

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm developing my first module on Prestashop that consists in creating products from xlsx files.

I was able to display a custom error message on the upload method but I'm not able to display a success message.

The bellow code works and I get a custom error message:

```
 if (file_exists($this->uploadDirectory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES["file"]['name'])) {
            $this->context->smarty->assign('error', 'O ficheiro já existe!');
            $this->uploadError = true;
            return false;
   }
```

The code bellow works but I don't get any success message:

```
if (!$this->uploadError) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $this->uploadDirectory. $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                $this->context->smarty->assign('success', "O ficheiro " . $file['name'] . " foi gravado com sucesso.");
                return true;
            }
        }
```

getContent function code:

```
/**
     * Load the configuration form
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        /**
         * If values have been submitted in the form, process.
         */
        if (((bool)Tools::isSubmit('submitExpodirectModule')) == true) {
            $this->postProcess();
        }

        $this->context->smarty->assign('module_dir', $this->_path);

        $output = $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path.'views/templates/admin/configure.tpl');

        $outputEnd= $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path.'views/templates/admin/table.tpl');


        return $output.$this->renderForm().$outputEnd;
    }
```

Comment: Show your getContent() method and tell us how those 2 pieces of code are invoked.

Comment: I've published my getContent() function, but maybe it's the best to publish the whole class? What do you say about it?

Comment: @Arun Vishwakarama's answer should work fine. Your getContent method belongs to a class which extends Module class, right?

Comment: Yes, I generated the module via prestashop module generator and  the class extends Module

Answer (score 0):

Use this in getContent when you got success from uploading and add this in output

$success_message = $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Message to be shown there .'));

return $success_message.form content and other output

Comment: Hello Arun, thanks for your answer. I've tried that before. It doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you show some code and in which function you write this ?

Comment: Hello Arunl, i've edited my post and added the getContent() function code

Comment: Ok you are using at module page